# drools-mvel is not present after the upgrade of the drools-decisiontables library from 7.67 to 8.31 due to that MissingDependencyException occurring

Tags: drools

drools-mvel was part of drools-template in 7.67 of drools-decisiontable library. It is removed now in 8.32. Due to this I am facing following exception in the application.

Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.drools.core.common.MissingDependencyException: You're trying to compile a Drools asset without mvel. Please add the module org.drools:drools-mvel to your classpath

I need to know the reason of removing org.drools:drools-mvel in drools-template of drools-decisiontable library.

Comment: Why is the reason for the removal important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nice thing about Open Source projects is that all the information is available.
It appears that the reason to decouple mvel from Drools was because of Quarkus (and I suspect this has to do with the Graalvm and native code generation): https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KOGITO-2852

The simple solution is to add the maven artifact that the error message is mentioning:

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
      <artifactId>drools-mvel</artifactId>
      <version>8.32</version>
 </dependency>
```

Hope it helps,