# org.drools.core.util.MVELSafeHelper is not available in 7.74.1.Final drools version

Tags: java, drools, java-17

I'm updating drools version from 7.20.0.Final to 7.74.1.Final. After update the dependency to 7.74.1.Final, I got an error saying couldn't find org.drools.core.util.MVELSafeHelper.

I have following code and need to do this without MVELSafeHelper.

```
    class Checker {

        private Object processTypeDataValue(String key, Object value) {
            if (!(value instanceof String)) {
                return value;
            }

            try {
                return MVELSafeHelper.getEvaluator().eval((String) value);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.warn("Problem evaluating metadata through MVEL", e);
                return value;
            }
        }

    }
```

Any alternative way to do this without MVELSafeHelper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a duplicate of: [drools-mvel is not present after the upgrade of the drools-decisiontables library from 7.67 to 8.31 due to that MissingDependencyException occurring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74884571/drools-mvel-is-not-present-after-the-upgrade-of-the-drools-decisiontables-librar)

The MVEL integration with Drools was moved to a `drools-mvel` artifact. Try adding the following dependency to your project:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
      <artifactId>drools-mvel</artifactId>
      <version>7.74.1</version>
</dependency>
```